# How do I add multiple custom CSS classes to Views references field?

Tags: 7, views, entities

As a follow up to [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/245693/how-do-i-add-multiple-custom-css-classes-to-views-rows/245713#245713) I need to resolve the same issue for [References module](http://drupal.org/project/references), in concrete the views integration.

When defining References Views display, no CSS classes can be added to rows (in difference to other display types like Page or Block).

So I try to output taxonomy tags with custom CSS classes using fields and get this:

```
<span class="field-content tag1-tag2-tag3">Tag1, Tag2, Tag3</span>
```

Now again I would need to output every taxonomy tag as a separate class. I would need spaces instead of - so the output would be something like that:

```
<span class="field-content tag1 tag2 tag3">Tag1, Tag2, Tag3</span>
```

I suppose that there is a bug in "references_plugin_style.inc" file from References plugin...

Comment: You may take a look at the views issue queue and how it's solved there and either file a bug report for the Reference module or propose a patch yourself. I think that would probably get things started.

Comment: Actually I just noticed that multivalue CSS classes neither do work in Views  for fields, they also get written with dashes like tag1-tag2-tag3. So the problem seems to go a little bit further. But I take your hint and check bug reports...